# Numba does not speed up code found in "speed up your code using numba" examples online

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I decided to start using [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) to speed up some scientific code I have. To get my feet wet, I googled and found some tutorials that provide runtimes. The tutorial example I'm referring to comes from [here](https://thedatafrog.com/en/articles/make-python-fast-numba/). They calculate the standard deviation from a numpy array, and then do it again using the @njit decorator from Numba, and then they compare the runtimes. Here's my attempt at recreating this code on my computer:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import numba
from timeit import timeit

def std(xs):
    # compute the mean
    mean = 0
    for x in xs:
        mean += x
    mean /= len(xs)
    # compute the variance
    ms = 0
    for x in xs:
        ms += (x - mean) ** 2
    variance = ms / len(xs)
    std = math.sqrt(variance)
    return std

c_std = numba.njit(std)

a = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10000)
```

Now here is what I get in terms of timing:

```
print(timeit('std(a)', globals=globals(), number=1) * 1000, 'ms')
```

runs in 9 ms. However, when I incorporate Numba:

```
print(timeit('c_std(a)', globals=globals(), number=1) * 1000, 'ms')
```

runs in 375 ms.

That's a **slowdown** of about 40x. In the tutorial, using the same code, *their* Numba-jitted code runs in 31.6 ms, compared to 4600 ms without Numba, for a speedup of about 150x. The only difference between our codes that I can see is that their normal distribution samples from 10,000,000 points, whereas mine is just 10,000, but this was a necessary adjustment since it took too long to run more points.

I'm on Python 3.8 using Numpy 1.19.2, and Numba 0.51.2. I'm running conda 4.9.2 on MacOs 10.14.

Comment: You're timing compilation!

Comment: But isn't that what they do in the tutorial..?

Comment: I thought compilation happens here: `c_std = numba.njit(std)`

Comment: From the tutorial you were reading: "Also, please keep in mind that the first time the function is called, numba will need to compile the function, which takes a bit of time." They time the function *after* calling it once to get it compiled.

Comment: I see. But I run my .py file multiple times. Does it not remember the compilation in a *.pyc file? Let me know if you have any advice, I'll see if I can extract the compilation part out.

Comment: Wow. You're right! I run c_std(a) once BEFORE timing it, and then it blazes in the timeit function -- 22 µs! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Monica's comment for pointing out that I was timing compilation. This is fixed right up when I run `c_std` once *before* timing it:

```
# Run once to compile~!
std(a)
c_std(a)

time_a = timeit('std(a)', globals=globals(), number=1) * 1000
print(f'No numba: {time_a:.3f} ms')

time_b = timeit('c_std(a)', globals=globals(), number=1) * 1000
print(f'Yes numba: {time_b:.3f} ms')
```

returns:

No numba: 9.024 ms

Yes numba: 0.025 ms

Comment: Yes the Numba generation of byte code for the specific PC it runs on (specific processor) takes a while.  I have code segments that take 15s on run #1 and then run #2 they only take 0.2s.  Unfortunately, using @ngit(cache=True) does not fix this "first run" issue.  Because it is compiling to your specific processor.  I wish there was a generic "compile for x64 processors" but as far as I can tell, there is not such a cache method.  If there is a generic compilation I don't know about, well, it's not in the docs.  In fact, I'm interested if such an argument exists in the numba @njit decorator.